# Trying to use watermark.js on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, watermark

I am trying to using the watermark.js plugin, but only want to stamp the image with watermark on a click event. That is, I do not want all the images to have the watermark only the ones with a click event or change event. The way I am doing is initiating the watermark plugin, and adding class 'watermark' to images on a click submit event but it is not working. Can any one please guide me how to go about it.

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en-us">

            <head>
                <title>watermark.js basic demo</title>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
                <div style="width:500px;position:relative;margin:auto;">
                    <h1>watermark.js basic demo</h1><a href="http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/">Back to watermark.js</a> The first and the third image will get a predefined watermark:
                    <img src="img/1.png" class="watermark" />
                    <img src="img/2.png" id="water" />
                    <img src="img/3.png" id="water" />
                </div>
                <form action="">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
                <!-- Look at the configuration -->
                <script src="watermark.js"></script>
                <script>
                var load = false;
                window.onload = function() {
                    if (!load) {
                        wmark.init({
                            /* config goes here */
                            "position": "top-left", // default "bottom-right"
                            "opacity": 100, // default 50
                            "className": "watermark", // default "watermark"
                            "path": "water.png"
                        });

                        load = true;
                    }
                }
                </script>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("form").submit(function() {
                        $("img").addClass("watermark");
                    });
                });
                </script>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, The watarmark is added to an image that has a defined class. So you could dynamically add the classname 'watermark' to a clicked image. Then run the wmark.init command to render the watermark effect. Using jquery this would be easy.

JS/ Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('img').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('watermark');

        wmark.init({
            /* config goes here */
            "position": "bottom-right",
            "opacity": 50,
            "className": "watermark",
            "path": "water.png"
        });
        // Remove class after the mark has been applied
        // This way it doesn't re-render the watermark when you
        // click another image
        $(this).removeClass('watermark');
    });

});
```

The $('img') selector can be any replaced with a classname you could assign to the images you want to be markable.

HTML

```
<img src="img1.jpg class="markable"> 
<img src="img2.jpg>
<img src="img3.jpg class="markable">
```

JS/ Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.markable').on('click', function(){
    ... ... etc
    ... ... etc
});
```